# Pass command line parameters to uwsgi script

Tags: python, wsgi, uwsgi

I'm trying to pass arguments to an example wsgi application, :

```
config_file = sys.argv[1]

def application(env, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
    return [b"Hello World %s" % config_file]
```

And run:

```
uwsgi --http :9090 --wsgi-file test_uwsgi.py  -???? config_file # argument for wsgi script
```

Any smart way I can achieve it? Couldn't find it in uwsgi docs. Maybe there is another way of providing some parameters to the wsgi application? (env. variables are out of scope)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

python args:

--pyargv "foo bar"

```
sys.argv
['uwsgi', 'foo', 'bar']
```

uwsgi options:

--set foo=bar

```
uwsgi.opt['foo']
'bar'
```

Comment: Shouldn't your `sys.argv` be `['uwsgi', 'foo', 'bar']`?

Comment: `--pyargv "foo bar"` works nicely with `argparse` too.

Answer (score 6):

You could use an .ini file with the `pyargv` setting that @roberto mentioned. Let's call our config file `uwsgi.ini` and use the content:

```
[uwsgi]
wsgi-file=/path/to/test_uwsgi.py
pyargv=human
```

Then let's create a WGSI app to test it:

```
import sys
def application(env, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
    return [str.encode("Hello " + str(sys.argv[1]), 'utf-8')]
```

You can see how to load this file https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Configuration.html#loading-configuration-files:

```
 uwsgi --ini /path/to/uwsgi.ini --http :8080
```

Then when we `curl` the app, we can see our param echoed back:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080
Hello human
```

If you are trying to pass argparse style arguments to your WSGI app, they work just fine in the `.ini` too:

```
pyargv=-y /config.yml
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using an env variable but setting it inside a start script:

```
def start(uwsgi_conf, app_conf, logto):
    env = dict(os.environ)
    env[TG_CONFIG_ENV_NAME] = app_conf
    command = ('-c', uwsgi_conf, '--logto', logto, )
    os.execve(os.path.join(distutils.sysconfig.get_config_var('prefix'),'bin', 'uwsgi'), command, env)
```